# Any way to get serving PLMN and mobile techno (hspa+, hsdpa, lte..) in iOS objective-C?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

Is there any way to get details on the DATA connection such as technology used (EDGE, HSPA, HSPA+, HSDPA, LTE, etc.) and serving PLMN?

This information is in Field test mode but don't know how to read this from my app?

I think this is not confidential/personal data, so why doesn't Apple give access to that?

Anyone know a private API that can do this job?

Comment: You can try reverse engineering the FieldTest app...